# Objective C - Defining macro to call a method?

Tags: objective-c, macros

I want to define a macro to call the following, Is this possible?
I also want it to accept format string.

```
- (void)logString:(NSString *)string withLogLogLevel:(LogLevel)logLevel
{
   // Sav log to file
}

DLog("text");
[Logger logString:text withLogLevel:LogLevelDebug];

ILog("text");
[Logger logString:text withLogLevel:LogLevelInfo];

ELog("text");
[Logger logString:text withLogLevel:LogLevelInfo];
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want.

Comment: I want to define a macro that calls a method with required parameters

Comment: While it's pretty easy to do what you've asked (see @dasblinkenlight's answer for a very simple approach), the logging problem is somewhat complex to do well, and there are good pre-built solutions to take care of this for you. See https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack for a good example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that `logString:withLogLevel:` takes a single string parameter in addition to the log level, this should be possible:

```
#define DLog(x) [Logger logString:(x) withLogLevel:LogLevelDebug]
```

Note the parentheses around the macro parameter, it is useful when macros are called with composite expressions.

Assuming that the logger takes `NSString` objects, not C string, you should use the macro like this:

DLog(@"Text");

However, in this case it is not clear why would one prefer a macro to a simple function call:

```
void DLog(NSString *str) {
    [Logger logString:str withLogLevel:LogLevelDebug];
}
```

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` are worth mentioning, IMHO.