# iOS - Globally change MBProgressHUD design

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I use MBProgressHUD for loading screens in my app. I have 26 occurrences where I use a different HUD.

Now, I've decided to use a customised UIView (an animated UIImageView) for the HUD. I want to apply this to all the HUD's I use in my app, but the code to customise the HUD is about 15 lines long, and it's definitely not the right method to add this code to every single occurrence of a MBProgressHUD in my app.

What's the right way to go from here? This is not the first time I've run into an issue like this where I'm not sure how to keep my code cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to declare the spinner in the AppDelegate, and write the methods `showSpinner` and `hideSpinner`, and also define a [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868883/objective-c-defining-macro-to-call-a-method) to call these spinner methods.

And you can just use this macro globally in your project.It is also easy to change the spinner code in the app delegate and you don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can

**1) subclass** your MBProgressHUD so you don't touch your library you have embedded

**2) Modify** this properties and parameters in that subclass. It should be styled right here, as you don't have to do it in multiple places in your code.

**3) Then call** that **subclass** anywhere, as it would be that same class, you had called before.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a category on `MBProgressHUD` to return a customized instance of your HUD, and then import this to places where you use it, or in your `AppName_Prefix.pch` file to import it everywhere.

So, it would look something like this:

In `MBProgressHUD+Additions.h`:

`+ (MBProgressHUD *)myCustomizedHUD;`

In `MBProgressHUD+Additions.m`

```
+ (MBProgressHUD *)myCustomizedHUD {
   MBProgressHUD *myHUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init]; 
   // customize 
   return myHud; 
}
```