# IOS/Objective-C: Methods to start and end uiactivityindicatorview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to create methods that I can reuse to start and stop spinning wheels during different lengthy activities such as syncing a table with a server.

My start method:

```
-(void) startSpinner {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }
```

and end method

```
-(void)endSpinner:(UIActivityIndicatorView *) spinner forTable:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [tableView reloadData];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is the end method does not recognize the uiactivityidicator created in the start method.

Should I be saving this in a property?  Or how can I grab the spinner from a different method in order to save it.

I'd like to set this up in reusable code as I have many tableviews in different view controllers where I would like to include this code.  The tableviews already have properties but do I have to set up a uiactivityindicator property in every view controller where I want to include a spinner?

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: you should declare a property of activity indicator and use it in both start and stop methods. Please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317179/ios-globally-change-mbprogresshud-design/39317998#39317998. ALso you should not initialise a new instance in start method if you already have reference to the old instance.

Comment: Do I alloc init the activity indicator in the method as above or in the VC prior to calling the method?

Comment: No, you do alloc init only once. PLease refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a property in AppDelegate:

```
   @property (strong,nonatomic) MyActivityIndicator *activity;
```

and initialise it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    _activity=[[MyActivityIndicator alloc]init];
}
```

and then declare the following methods in appDelegate:

```
- (void)showActivity
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_window addSubview:_activity];
        [_activity startAnimating];
    });

}

- (void)hideActivity
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //also remove activity from window
        [_activity stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

you can call these two methods from any class:

```
  [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate showActivity];
```

Comment: What is MyActivityIndicator.  Is this a separate class?  Can I use UIActivityIndicatorView?

Comment: I subclassed the UIActivityIndicatorView, you can just use UIActivityIndicatorView inplace of it